# Allocator failing with higher numbers

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I have school project to create memory allocator. I´ve been debugging it over 3 days now with no reasonable outcome. It is suddenly failing when higher number is ment to be allocated for example i have an array of 65000Bytes and I want to allocate 12000, it fails. Lower numbers up to 800 work great tho.

Let´s say we have static array consisting of 65000Bytes.
We call init, which creates linked list which has pointer to next list and size of list. We also are allowed to have one global variable for pointer to start of array I named mine "start".
Looks like this:

```
typedef struct mallocstr head;
char* start;

struct mallocstr
{
    head* next; //For moving through list
    int size; //If allocated then value is <0
};
```

And here is my allocator function:

```
void* memory_alloc(unsigned int size)
{
    head* p = start;
    char* endd= end();
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->size > 0 && p->size >= size + sizeof(p) && size != 0)
        {
            int newsize = p->size - size - sizeof(p);
            //If head is smaller than newsize create next block and allocate this one
            if (sizeof(p) < newsize)
            {
                hlavicka* var;
                p->size = (p->size - newsize) * (-1);
                int point = p->size;
                point*= -1;
                p->next= p + sizeof(p) + point;
                var= p;
                p = p->next;
                p->size= newsize;
                p->next = NULL;
                return  (void*)var + 2*(sizeof(int));
            }
            //If head is greater or same as newsize
            else if (sizeof(p) >= newsize)
            {
                p->size= p->size* (-1);
                p->next = NULL;
                return  (void*)p + 2*(sizeof(int));
            }
        }
        //If we are unable to alocate this block because size is too small or it is allocated we move to 
        //next one
        else if (p->size< size + sizeof(p) && p != endd|| p->size< 0)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        //When we cannot allocate any block
        else if (p->size < size + sizeof(p) && p == endd|| size == 0)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Function end is for getting pointer to the end of list. Here it is:

```
void* end()
{
    head* p = start;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p->next== NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            p = p->next;
    }
    return (void*)p;
}
```

Comment: What is `hlavicka`?

Comment: `return  p + sizeof(p);` That looks fishy. Since `p` is a pointer that statement is doing pointer arithmetic. It's not skipping forward just one `head` size. That can't really be what you intend right? It's going forward `sizeof(p)*sizeof(*p)`. Probably should be `return p+1`.

Comment: @KamilCuk my bad, i translated my code to english to make it more understandful for you, i missed that one, now edited. It is head shortcut.

Comment: Because `p` is a pointer, `sizeof(p)` is the size of the pointer itself (and not what it points to), is that really what you want?

Comment: @WhozCraig another mistake I made translating code, I edited it, it should be more clear now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I need to go from pointer to pointer + head to return pointer that is pointing to first free Byte of allocated memory.

Comment: Run your code under `valgrind` and check what it reports.

Comment: "I need to go from pointer to pointer + head". That's not what you are doing. You are skipping more than one head. Are you familiar with pointer arithmetic?

Comment: I thought of it like array. My head is 8Bytes long, I want to move from for example p is pointing to arr[0] so i want it to point to arr + 8 which is arr[8] to then return pointer pointing to arr[8].

Comment: `arr[8]` is not the same as 8 bytes from the start of the array unless the array elements are a single byte. `arr[8]` is `8*sizeof(array[0])` bytes from the start of the array. So if the elements are 8 bytes then it will be 64 bytes from the start of the array and not 8 as you intend.

Comment: It is char array so it should have 1 block of size 1Byte if I´m not mistaken

Comment: I have updated return values to return  (void*)p + 2*(sizeof(int)); I hope it is correct now, code stil won´t allocate higher values tho

Comment: But p is not a char array. So p+sizeof(p) is returning 4*8 or 8*8 bytes from p depending on pointer sizes on your system. You want just 8 bytes from p.

Comment: Yes I do, but I have no idea on how else to return it.

Comment: I told you. `p+1`

Comment: That would move it from p to p+8Bytes?

Comment: Yes. Look up "pointer arithmetic" for a more detailed explanation.